# can we send messages to user even when the application is closed in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i m making an application where data is accesed from website and displayed with an application.i have made an action which will tell the user that new data has arrived.this will work properly if the application is open .but if the application is closed than ,is there any way to tell the user that new data has arrived ,,so that he can open the application and check the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the Apple Push Notification Service (APNs), your messages will be delivered whether the application is running or not. For information on how to control what information is presented to the user, read the [Apple Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), like codelark said.

I would recommend looking into [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) for help getting started. It's a third party service, but it makes things much easier. Urban Airship does have their own tutorials and code samples which may be easier than Apple's.

Comment: Moshe, we need someone to go through the 300k or so questions and answers here and correct all of them for spelling and grammar errors.  You seem like the man for the job.  When can you start?  Did I mention the effort it would take to fix all the spelling and grammar errors here would consume your entire day, 7 days a week, 52 weeks a year, until you get planted in a pine box?

Comment: Will - If an admin or mod could "flip a switch" and enable me to edit spelling and grammar, I would definitely help out. It's the least I can do. I just noticed that I have a terrible question to answer ratio.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to the reference to apple push notification, as of ios4.0 I believe you, you may have a few more options, 1) you can send local notifications (just like push notifications, but they originate from inside your app) that could be timed to be delivered even if the app is not running..assuming you know approximately how long it will take for data to arrive. 2) if your data update will occur soon after the app closed.. your app can request a certain amount of time to complete an operation (even though the user has closed the app) and wait for the data, then send a local notification to tell the person to come back into the app.  3) if your functions based on gps updates, music streaming, or voip you can set a flag so your app continues to run in the background

sorry for the unstructuredness of the answer, this was just off the top of my head, hope it helps